# I ran 'git pull' but still can't automatically merge?

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm working on a feature branch, which will eventually be merged into `origin/develop` once my pull request is accepted.

Before pushing my branch up to origin, I ran:

`$ git pull origin develop`

After pushing my changes to `origin/<feature-branch>`, Github says it "Can't automatically merge" and that this branch is "3 commits ahead, 12 commits behind develop".

What did I do wrong, and how can I make sure my local branch is up to date with `origin/develop` before pushing up my changes, so that a fast-forward merge is possible?

**Workflow**

1) `$ git clone <origin-url>`

2) `$ git checkout <feature-branch>`

3) Make changes to code, stage and commit them

4) `$ git checkout develop`

5) `$ git pull origin develop`

6) `$ git checkout <feature-branch>`

6) `$ git push origin <feature-branch>`

Comment: I can't figure out what is going on here.  What actual command did you use to push your changes to `origin/<feature/branch>`?  And why is Git telling you how much the branch has diverged from _develop_?  Shouldn't it be reporting on the feature branch.  Can you edit your question and list the exact steps you took to arrive at where you are now?

Comment: Apologies for lack of clarity here - I've added my workflow.

Comment: I don't actually see the step which generated the `Can't automatically merge` message, AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

That means that your pull request can't be merged into the upstream without the upstream owner(s) having to resolve merge conflicts.

The resolution here would be for you to do a fetch from the upstream and then resolve the merge conflicts from the upstream. At this point, if you theoretically resolve the conflicts from the upstream and then create your pull request, upstream would be able to automatically merge in your pull request without having any conflicts (provided there were no commits on the upstream between you locally resolving the upstream merge conflicts and merging into your local/fork, and then creating the pull request).

**Solution**:

In Github select branches tab, click merge view button, drag your head fork to the left box, drag your base fork to the right box. Click Merge Branches button. Select changes tab. Select each file that has conflicts. see '`<<<<<<<`' Edit files in external viewer to keep headfork code and add yours to it. Click Save on file(s). Click Commit to button. Click sync. Go to Git website and try merging your base fork to head fork again. It should no longer show the original message

Answer (score 1):

with “git pull origin develop”, you're just pulling the latest changes from the remote develop branch to your local develop branch, you're not merging the latest changes to your feature branch. You'll have to do so locally by using [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

```
git merge develop
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do two things that you are not currently doing:

1. (optional) like Patrick says, merge develop into feature-branch. This will bring your branch up to speed with develop like you wanted. Anyway, it is good practice and might be mandated by your team's workflow.
2. Pull feature-branch before you push it. This could be what gives you the error. I would pull before merging with develop as well.